# Modifying \part style in documentclass book

Tags: titlesec, epigraphs

I am new to LaTeX and this forum.

I used a solution given in the forum that fit my needs. Except that I would like to add a horizontal line under the part title and before the epigraph. If someone could help? I'm losing time reading the `titlesec` documentation in english (I'm french....) and I have to write my memoir....

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\Huge\scshape\filright}
  {\partname~\thepart:}
  {20pt}
  {\thispagestyle{epigraph}}
\makeatother
\setlength\epigraphwidth{.6\textwidth}


\begin{document}

\epigraphhead[450]{Fairy tales are more than true: not because they tell us that dragons exist, but because they tell us dragons can be beaten.\par\hfill\textsc{C.K. Chesterton}}
\part{A Test Part Title}

\end{document}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\Huge\scshape\filright}
  {\partname~\thepart:}
  {20pt}
  {\thispagestyle{epigraph}}
\makeatother
\setlength\epigraphwidth{.6\textwidth}


\begin{document}

\epigraphhead[450]{Fairy tales are more than true: not because they tell us that dragons exist, but because they tell us dragons can be beaten.\par\hfill\textsc{C.K. Chesterton}}
\part{A Test Part Title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is this what you want to achieve? https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4F3e.png

Comment: If you are writing your memoir you might consider using the `memoir` class :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Reading the documentation is not wasting time. ;-) There are good examples to get inspiration from in the appendix of the `titlesec` manual. Here are a few options, depending on what you want (one or two rules? that wasn't completely clear in your question).

## Two rules: after title and before epigraph

If the rule preceding the epigraph has to fill the whole body text width:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\normalfont\Huge\scshape}
  {\partname~\thepart}
  {10pt}
  {\thispagestyle{epigraph}}
  [\vspace*{.8ex}\titlerule]

\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{.6\textwidth}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}

\newlength{\maintextwidth}
\setlength{\maintextwidth}{\textwidth}

\newcommand{\myepigraph}[3][450]{%
  \epigraphhead[#1]{%
    \hspace*{\dimexpr -\maintextwidth+\epigraphwidth}%
    \hrulefill\par
    \epigraph{#2}{#3}}}

\begin{document}

\myepigraph{Fairy tales are more than true: not because they tell us that
  dragons exist, but because they tell us dragons can be beaten.}
  {\textsc{C.K.~Chesterton}}
\part{A Test Part Title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, if the rule preceding the epigraph should only fill the epigraph width, simply comment out the line:

```latex
\hspace*{\dimexpr -\maintextwidth+\epigraphwidth}%
```

and you'll obtain:

[image]

## No rule before the epigraph

Here, we only draw one horizontal rule: after the tile. Juste use:

```latex
\newcommand{\myepigraph}[3][450]{%
  \epigraphhead[#1]{%
    \epigraph{#2}{#3}}}
```

in the above code.

[image]

Finally, in case you want a first rule just before the part label and a second rule just after the part title, you can use:

```latex
\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\titlerule\vspace*{.8ex}\normalfont\Huge\scshape}
  {\partname~\thepart}
  {10pt}
  {\thispagestyle{epigraph}}
  [\titlerule]
```

[image]